# android setBackgroundDrawable is not working

Tags: android

This one 12 hours debugging..help me..

res/drawable

```
    main_img1.png
    main_img2.png
```

xml

```
    android:background="@drawable/main_img1"
```

Member

```
    RelativeLayout relativelayout;
```

oncreate

```
    relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this);  
    relativelayout.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_img2));
    relativelayout.invalidate();
```

image is not change
setBackgroundDrawable is not working
no error no redline

You can not use an imageview,
the change dynamically to the background of the layout, the handler

Please share your knowledge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to let the RelativeLayout know which Resource you're refering to:

xml

```
android:id="@+id/your_layout"
android:background="@drawable/main_img1"
```

oncreate

```
relativelayout = new RelativeLayout(this); 
relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout)
```

Comment: id is not defined to xml file

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your drawable is missing its intrinsic bounds. So, instead of `setBackgroundDrawable`, use `setBackgroundResource` and let the view adjust bounds automatically.

For example

```
relativelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_img2);
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

xml:

```
android:background="@drawable/main_img1"
```

oncreate

```
  RelativeLayout relativelayout;
relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout)
    relativelayout.setBackgroudResource(null);
    relativelayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_img2);
```

I hope its useful to you.

Comment: Thanks for your kindness, @dipali Your kindness, I sleep tonight

Comment: setBackgroudResource takes an int and cannot be set to null

Answer (score 0):

Do this way;

XML:

```
        <RelativeLayout>
          android:id="@+id/rel_layout"
          android:background"@drawable/main_img1"
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Java:

```
       RelativeLayut rel_layout=(RelativeLayout)findviewbyId(R.id.rel_layout);
       rel_layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.main_img2);
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindness.@Balvinder Singh ! Your kindness, I sleep tonight

Answer (score 0):

The method setBackgroundDrawable is deprecated. Instead use

```
setBackgroundResource(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.main_img2));
```

Also get reference to your layout from xml as below

```
relativelayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.your_layout);
```